# Altering CartThrob CSV export settings

Tags: cartthrob, csv

A client uses the purchased_item_notes field for customer order notes, and would like to export those in the order reports. This purchased_item_notes content displays on the CMS view of the generated order report, but when you export to CSV, the file trims away the data from that field.

Is it possible to alter the CSV export settings to include all the data in the generated report?

Using CartThrob Order Manager 2.5 and EE 2.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Do can do a custom report and have it format it exactly then way you want. I do this and use the http_header add-on to generate an cvs that downloads at the click of a button and gets imported into Xero. The other advantage is that your client does not have to select all those report options each time they want to generate a report.